# Error while registering to broadcast receiver

Tags: android, exception, broadcastreceiver, memory-leaks

I am writing a small program that gets activated when sms is received.We need to start/stop service through graphical user interface. I am using a check box and a button to start or stop the service.

The code is as followed.

```
 private smsBroadcast b;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

 }

public void onclick(View i)
{
    CheckBox c=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
      b=new smsBroadcast();
    try{
    if(c.isChecked())
    registerReceiver(b, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
    else
    unregisterReceiver(b);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
    finish();
}
```

Here smsBroadcast is the broadcastReceiver class.
When we click the button, it is showing some exceptions in logcat.
The exceptions are as followed...

```
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806): Activity examples.sms.SmssmsActivity has leaked IntentReceiver examples.sms.smsBroadcast@405457f0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity examples.sms.SmssmsActivity has leaked IntentReceiver examples.sms.smsBroadcast@405457f0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806):   at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:756)
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806):   at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:551)
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806):   at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:795)
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806):   at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:782)
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806):   at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:776)
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806):   at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:318)
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806):   at examples.sms.SmssmsActivity.onclick(SmssmsActivity.java:25)
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806):   at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
           03-31 12:01:33.923: E/ActivityThread(806):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: How are you using onclick? it could be that you are registering multiple receivers and never unregistering them causing a leak. IMO you are using revers all wrong. You should register it once in onResume and use on click to set a boolean checked by your rcver. You should also unreg in onPause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to register the receiver in onResume and unregister in onPause

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

If registering a receiver in your Activity.onResume() implementation, you should unregister it in Activity.onPause(). (You won't receive intents when paused, and this will cut down on unnecessary system overhead). Do not unregister in Activity.onSaveInstanceState(), because this won't be called if the user moves back in the history stack.

Comment: SO, is there any mechanism to dynamiclly register and unregister...
here i am registering in onclick() method!

Comment: but where do you unregister it?

Comment: when we uncheck the checkbox, we unregister it

Comment: sorry... too lazy to read your code. 3 am here. but please follow the doc for now and register/unregister in onResume/onPause

Answer (score 0):

Appears that you created more `IntentReceivers` than Android can handle.  you should use `unregisterReceiver()` when you don't need more Receiver.